# restart Apache when down centos 6

Tags: apache, shell

I need shell script to restart HTTPD when down. I was search on web found some script but its not working showing syntax error.

```
#!/bin/bash
RESTART="/sbin/service httpd restart"
PGREP="/usr/bin/pgrep"
HTTPD="httpd"
$PGREP ${HTTPD}
if [ $? -ne 0 ] # if apache not running 
then
# restart apache
$RESTART
fi
```

and when i run this script its showing error

```
[root@vmi194867 pydash]# bash -x /scripts/httpd.sh
: No such file or directory/usr/bin/pgrep // path is correct 
/scripts/httpd.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/scripts/httpd.sh: line 10: `fi'
```

Comment: A script to start a daemon? But that already exists... Something like `sudo service apache2 start`...

Comment: And by the way: `restart` does _not_ start the daemin if it is down. It _restarts_ it unconditionally, that means you break all requests currently served if the daemon actually runs.

Comment: `sudo yum whatprovides */pgrep` ...

Comment: Can you write right code and send me i try everything its not working